# Image in custom EditTextPreference doesn't change

Tags: android, layout, sharedpreferences

Hello I created PreferenceActivity class that loads all preferences from R.xml.preferences and shows them on the list R.layout.preference_list (the simplest layout with the list in it only).

The thing is one of the preference uses specific layout like

```
    <EditTextPreference
        android:title="@string/auth_title"
        android:summary="@string/auth_summary"
        android:key="pass"
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:layout="@layout/preference_auth"
        android:hint="Enter password"/>
```

where the crucial attribute here in this `@layout/preference_auth` layout is

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconSelected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_no" />
```

and it describes the icon on the right side. Left side is clickable preference which opens EditText area.

[image]

Now I want to programatically change the image src that is shown on screen when EditText matches to specific string.

I havePreferenceActivity class

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {

 private EditTextPreference editPref;
 private ImageView icon;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
                setContentView(R.layout.preference_list);

                editPref = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("pass");

                icon = (ImageView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(editPref.getLayoutResource(), null).findViewById(R.id.iconSelected);
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_yes);

            }
}
```

And this code doesn't work. The image seems to be intact. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I found an answer. This preference activity is just responsible for displaying the view that is already configured in another class responsible for that. So I cut a bit of code like that

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {

   private ImageView icon;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
       setContentView(R.layout.preference_list);
   }

}
```

where `R.xml.preferences` among others contains my custom EditTextPreference. When we extend this class we need to override `onBindView()` method which sets up the behaviour for example feature that I wanted to achieve in this topic. It finally looks like this

```
public class AuthPreference extends EditTextPreference {
        private ImageView icon;
        private boolean change;

        ...

        @Override
        protected void onBindView(View view) {
            super.onBindView(view);
            icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconSelected);
            if(change) icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_yes);
            else icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_no);
        }
}
```

where the icon src is controlled by `getSharedPreferences().getString()`. Now it works fine.